# Outlook troubles moving mails to trash

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently changed webhost, and therefore I needed to reinstall mail stuff etc., and now I can't use the regular delete functions in my Outlook client, nor on my iPhone.

The mailfolder for trash is indented under "Inbox", which makes the problem occur, but how to I make it work again? I've tried almost everything through Outlook, and I can't seem to find a solution.

For webhosting panel, I use cPanel, if something is needed done from there.

Comment: Can you manually create a Trash folder in the place that Outlook and iPhone expects on the mail server? Its really a webhost question... not having to do with Outlook client itself I think. You are using IMAP I presume? or Exchange?

Comment: @sunk818 The foldes are existing, but as mentioned earlier, they're indented under "inbox", and iPhone mail and Outlook can't find them because of that. I have tried just un-indent them, but that didn't help.

Comment: I think you had a bad migration.